# UITableView Disable the row where not visible to user

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView with (990x580 pixels), where within each cell of the table there is a text field, the text fields are differentiated by the tag:

```
cell.myTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Assuming I have 20 rows in my table, causing me to see all rows of the table will have to use the scroll (since the table only has 990x598 pixels)

Assuming that we are looking to line number 20 of the table, and the line number 1 is no longer visible (unless if I use scroll to go up), I would like to know why when I try to pick up existing information within the text field whose tag is equal to 1 the application does not return me anything?

I realized that when this text field not visible to the User, it seems to become disabled, would like to find a way for it to not turn over the lines in which are not available to the User, this my Tableview below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{//Ja explicado anteriormente

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ComissoesTableViewCell";//Ja explicado anteriormente

    ComissoesTableViewCell *cell = (ComissoesTableViewCell *)[tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];//Ja explicado anteriormente

    if (cell == nil){//Ja explicado anteriormente

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ComissoesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];//Ja explicado anteriormente
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];//Ja explicado anteriormente
    }
    cell.data.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell:

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` works by automatically reusing cells when they scroll out of the visible part of your table. That makes the cell information to reset as you configure the reused cell again.

You need to store your persistent information at the viewController level (e.g., in a `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary`). Consider using an `NSDictionary` and storing your cell content `NSString`s indexed by the cell's indexPath.

---

Also note that the following

```
if (cell == nil){//Ja explicado anteriormente

    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ComissoesTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];//Ja explicado anteriormente
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];//Ja explicado anteriormente
}
```

is no longer recommended.

If you register a nib or class for your `simpleTableIdentifier` (e.g., using `- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`) it's guaranteed that the deque method won't ever return nil, as it will automatically create new cells as it needs them.